# Distance set of a Borel set is a Lebesgue set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Borel set and define $D(A) := \{|x-y| : x, y \in A \}$. How to show that $D(A)$ is a Lebesgue set? and maybe even possibly a Borel set? The only idea I have right now is to use the fact that Borel set under Lipschitz continuous function is a Lebesgue set, but I'm not sure how to continue. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The image of any Borel set under any Borel measurable function is Lebesgue measurable (look up analytic sets).

Comment: $D(A) = d(A \times A)$. where $d(x,y) = |x - y|$. If $A$ is Borel, then so is $A\times A$.